# Publish NuGet Packages from TeamCity to Azure DevOps Artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, teamcity

I am trying to configure the [Azure Artifacts Credential Provider](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099625) to allow me to connect to Azure DevOps and publish NuGet packages to the Artifacts feed. I have installed the credential provider on my build server. However every time that I run the build I get the following error:

[image]

Am I supposed to pass in a PAT to the Credential Provider or is the account that is running the build need to have access to Azure DevOps so that it can generate credentials? The documentation was a little unclear to me about how this works. My TeamCity instance is a little out of date so maybe I need to work on getting that upgraded first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please, add [NuGet Credentials Provider build feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/nuget-feed-credentials.html) for your build configuration. Specify an URL for the feed (the same way as you did in NuGet Publish build step), a valid username + PAT (not a password in there).

Comment: For benefit of others coming to this thread: this solution eliminates the need to install the "Azure Artifacts Credential Provider", available from Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you!  This finally worked for us after many other things we tried.  I wish this was more obvious.  The TeamCity Build Feature we used for this is titled "NuGet feed credentials".  This is in version 2021.1.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer seems to no longer be working.  On TeamCity 2019.1.4 running on Windows Server 2016 and using .NET Core 2.2.105:

```
[push] WARNING: The credential plugin model used by 'C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\nuget-agent\bin\credential-provider\CredentialProvider.TeamCity.exe' is deprecated. Please contact the provider of the plugin for an alternative. More information about the recommended plugin model can be found at 'https://aka.ms/nuget-cross-platform-authentication-plugin'.
[17:18:31][push] Please provide credentials for: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/org/project/_packaging/feed/nuget/v3/index.json
[17:18:31][push] Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/org/project/_packaging/feed/nuget/v3/index.json.
[17:18:31][push]   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

Manually installing and running the https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider works from the command line if I log in to the server and set the env vars for non-interactive use, but does not work within the context of a TeamCity Build job.

Is there a newer TeamCity runner than can handle authentication for dotnet nuget push to Azure Artifacts?

Comment: Addenda: I've updated to .NET Core SDK 3.1 and NuGet 5.1 and the accepted answer is now working.